# How to write reusable classes in css

Tags: css, less

This isn't a question of such, rather i just want to know rather my understanding on reusable class in CSS is correct. In this example, I have 2 divs. and i want to add a padding-left to both, but with different values. (e.g. div one has a padding left of 10px, and div2 and padding left of 15px). So Now I want to write reusable css classes, with the help of a less function.

**example1**

```
<div id="div1" class="small-left-space">
</div>

<div id="div2" class="large-left-space">
</div>
```

//css and less

```
.padLeft(@value)
{
   padding-left: @value;
}

.small-left-space{
  .padLeft(10px);
 }


.large-left-space{
  .padLeft(100px);
 }
```

**example 2**

Html

```
<div id="box1" class="bigBox redBackground smallLeftSpace "></div>

<div id="box2" class="mediumBox blueBackground mediumLeftSpace"></div>

<div id="box3" class="smallBox greenBackground largeLeftSpace"></div>
```

CSS/Less

```
  .bigBox
 {
   width: 500px;
   height:500px;
 }

.mediumBox{
    width:300px
    height:300px;
}

.smallBox{
   width:100px
   height:100px;
}

.redBackground{
   .backgroundColor(red);
}

.blueBackground{
   .backgroundColor(blue); 
}

.greenBackground{
    .backgroundColor(green);
}

.smallLeftSpace{
     margin-left: 20px;
}

.mediumLeftSpace{
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.largeLeftSpace{
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.backgroundColor(@value){
   background-color: @value;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As you're using Less, the best thing to do is to use **reusable mixins** instead of reusable classes.  It has several advantages :

- if the mixin is not used, it's not compiled and doesn't appears in your generated CSS
- your HTML markup is clean, semantic, without many cosmetic classes
- you can use one mixin (with a parameter) where you would have used several CSS classes

This is the way you make awesome, clean and reusable code.

Example:

**Less file, with mixins:**

```
/* Size */
.box(@value) {
    width: @value;
    height: @value;
}
.bigBox() {
    .box(500px);
}
.mediumBox() {
    .box(300px);
}
.smallBox() {
    .box(100px);
}

/* background-color */
.backgroundColor(@value){
    background-color: @value;
}

/* margin-left */
.leftSpace(@value) {
    margin-left: @value;
}
.smallLeftSpace() {
    .leftSpace(20px);
}
.mediumLeftSpace() {
    .leftSpace(50px);
}
.largeLeftSpace() {
    .leftSpace(100px);
}

#box2 {
    .mediumBox();
    .backgroundColor(blue);
    .mediumLeftSpace();
}
#box3 {
    .smallBox();
    .backgroundColor(green);
    .largeLeftSpace();
}
```

**CSS file, generated:**

```
#box2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0000ff;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
#box3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #008000;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

**HTML markup used, without cosmetic classes:**

```
<div id="box2"></div>
<div id="box3"></div>
```

Comment: +1, though speaking of the Less part I would say that *just* one property mixins never make sense at all (the CSS result is much more readable than the Less code in this case).